# jQuery google map title on location icon

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I want visible title on location in google map via jQuery api like http://s9.picofile.com/file/8304656450/map.JPG

My code :

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    title: "12",
    visible: true,
    icon: '/images/location.png'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: position,
   map: map,
   title: "12",
   label: "12",  // --- this is what you need to use.
   visible: true,
   icon: '/images/location.png'
});
```

You should use `label` to display value all the time on `marker`.

**Reference document:** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

One more fiddle link from google documents https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Hope this will help you.